PostgreSQL: cross Schema Foreign Keys fails with permission denied for table
Adding a cross-schema foreign key:
ALTER TABLE "editedArticles"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "editedArticles_articles_foreign"
  FOREIGN KEY("originalArticleId") REFERENCES "private".articles("id");

fails with:
ERROR:  42501: permission denied for table articles

even after successfully executing:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA private TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ON TABLE private."articles" TO postgres;

I seem to have the same problem as asked about in this unanswered question.
For the record:

SELECT current_user; returns postgres
\du+ postgres returns Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS

and finally:
postgres=> \dn+ private
                       List of schemas
  Name   |  Owner   |     Access privileges     | Description 
---------+----------+---------------------------+-------------
 private | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres     +| 
         |          | digest=UC/postgres       +| 
         |          | supabase_admin=U/postgres | 
(1 row)

postgres=> \z private.articles
                                     Access privileges
 Schema  |   Name   | Type  |       Access privileges       | Column privileges | Policies 
---------+----------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------+----------
 private | articles | table | digest=arwdDxt/digest        +|                   | 
         |          |       | supabase_admin=arwdDxt/digest+|                   | 
         |          |       | postgres=r/digest             |                   | 
(1 row)

Note that postgres=r/digest only has the r (read) permission on that table, not the x (references). But why? I executed GRANT REFERENCES (as mentioned above).

Turns out that the command:
GRANT SELECT, REFERENCES ON TABLE private."articles" TO postgres;

returned "Success. No rows returned" when executed with my postgres user, but it actually didn't do anything! But if I executed it with the digest user (that owns the private.articles table), then it returned "GRANT" and now it works.

It looks like your client suppresses warnings. There must have been a warning WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "private.articles".

@LaurenzAlbe good to know, thanks! I was using the supabase GUI. Won't make that mistake again.
